Power Automate to populate a Date/Time sharepoint column to use the site time zone?
I have a site content type named Asset, and this content type contains a site column of type Date/Time named ETA. now i am using KQL formula inside PnP Modern search web part to get all items which have their ETA equal today + have the Asset content type as follow:-

{searchTerms} ContentType:"Asset"
RefinableDate01=today


now i am facing this issues:-

in SharePoint online >> the date/time will be stored based on the UTC time, while my SharePoint site time zone is set to Pacific Time.
Also the "today" keyword inside the above formula will be based on UTC.
So if the current date time is 22 August @ 03:40 am Pacific Time + 10:40 am UTC.
And I added a list item and i defined the ETA Date/Time to "8/21/2024 10:00 pm"
This will be stored inside SharePoint using UTC which will be "2024-08-22T05:00:00Z".
So when i do a search using this Query Template: -


{searchTerms} ContentType:"Asset"
RefinableDate01=today


I will get the above item, although based on the site time zone which the users follow this item is not for today 22 August (based on their timezone) it is for yesterday 21 August..
so can i fix this using Power Automate? where i will define another field named ETAPacific? and define a scheduled flow which runs on the items modified in the last one hour, and update the ETA(Pacific) in a way that will work when i search for the items using this KQL :-

{searchTerms} ContentType:"Asset"
ETAPacific=today


any advice?
